Replacing metal fuel line with braided hose - Need 1/2 and 7/16 fittings for pump and carb
I changed a fuel pump (mechanical mounted below the alternator) on an IH V-345 motor with a 2bbl carb.
The carb has a 7/16 inlet and the fuel pump has a 1/2 inlet, both are female.
EDIT: Here is the fuel line - both ends have this 1/2 inch male fitting (the carb has a 7/16 to 1/2 adapter that the 1/2 male goes into. The issue is that the radiator host manifold (big iron interface) is right in front of the carb inlet so the adapter + fitting + another fitting won't fit)

Here's a small pic of the carb so you can see the manifold in front of it:

Looking at the braided hose, I don't understand what 7/16 and 1/2 inch fittings I need to put into the female carb and fuel-pump inlet/outlet to connect the hose.


The ends on the braided fuel line are called Spectraclamp. They are intended to clamp onto fuel hose fittings that look like this:

So if you are using this hose, ideally, what you need are 7/16" and 1/2" adapters from whatever female arrangements are on the fuel pump and carb to the 3/8" fuel hose fitting shown above.
You haven't said exactly what kind of 7/16" and 1/2" fittings were on the ends of the metal fuel line. If you don't know what they are called, post clear, close-up photos of both ends by using the EDIT link below your question and someone here can identify them for you.
Then you can search online for adapters based in industry standard nomenclature.

Thanks @MTA - edits made...

@mikeb That's a flare fitting and if I'm not mistaken it's a "double flare". Have a look at a Holley 26-44 fuel bowl inlet fitting, 90 degree elbow, as an example of what to look for. I can't really tell from your small picture, but you may be able to orient the 90 degree fitting to avoid interference with the manifold. This is made of 5/16 tubing and I believe you're looking for 3/8. I've also seen short elbows like this made of brass instead of tubing.

So the braided line will connect to this double flared inlet fitting?

@mikeb A double flared fitting seals as well as a fuel hose fitting, but you need the right size. Your hose is 3/8 so you need a 3/8 fitting. A 7/16 is smaller and may not seal well.

Understood - but what I'm asking is will this "spectraclamp" connect to a double-flared fitting?

If so, I can just cut like a 3 inch piece of this rigid steel with the 1/2 inch male fitting and make a double-flare. Then, screw the male fitting into the carb and clip on the clamp...

@mikeb Yes, that will work. But practice making a double flare on some scrap tubing first. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Irmh7B7OnHQ
